# Krajee Bootstrap File Input maxFileCount of Images

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, input, count

I am using Krajee's Bootstrap File Input.

http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input

I accomplished to put an image into that input field, thus that field shows the file /image I put in.

Now I tried to put in a few more images and changed the parameter

> maxFileCount

from 1 to 20,

I do not get any errors but the input field shows only one image,

does anyone knows how to solve this?

Code looks like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="LogoImage">pick images</label>
    <input id="input-imgs" name="input-image" type="file" class="file-loading" accept="image/*">
    <div id="kv-success-modal" class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Success!</h4>
                </div>
                <div id="kv-success-box" class="modal-body"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the javascript (jquery):

```
$("#input-imgs").fileinput({
    uploadUrl: "/site/image-upload",
    allowedFileExtensions: ["jpg", "png", "jpeg"],
    allowedFileTypes: ['image'],
    maxImageWidth: 1000,
    maxFileCount: 20,
    resizeImage: true
}).on('filepreupload', function() {
    $('#kv-success-box').html('');
}).on('fileuploaded', function(event, data) {
    $('#kv-success-box').append(data.response.link);
    $('#kv-success-modal').modal('show');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It works now, it is pretty simple I just added

> muliple

in the html.

so line changed to:

```
<input id="input-imgs" name="input-image" type="file" multiple class="file-loading" accept="image/*">
```